# Installing crt certificate without CSR on IIS6

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, iis-6, godaddy, csr

I renewed an ssl certificate on GoDaddy recently. It didn't ask me to generate a new CSR. It just gave me a .crt file.

How do I install this in IIS6. I already removed the expired certificate and installed the cer manually (plus the intermediate certificate) into the server's cert store, but it doesn't work - I can't access OWA. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need the .crt, the intermediate cert and the private key for the SSL to function properly.  If you don't have the private key any longer you can generate and new CSR and private key and re-key the SSL.  Once re-keyed you can then reinstall the new .crt and intermediate certificate.

Comment: That's worked. Pity I still can't recieve incoming mail from yahoo without getting a TLSSTART error, but that may be nothing to do with this.

Comment: Glad I was able to help with getting your SSL installed!